# The type 'DropDownField' is declared with 0 type parameters, but 1 type arguments were given

Tags: flutter, dart, dropdown

```
Widget locationList(String airportId) {
    return Container(
      child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Airports").doc(widget.airportId).collection("Locations").snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if(snapshot.data == null){
           return Container();
          } else {
            List<DropdownMenuItem<String>> locationItem = [];
            for(int i=0;i<snapshot.data!.docs.length;i++){
              DocumentSnapshot data = snapshot.data!.docs[i];
              locationItem.add(
                DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  child: Text(
                    data["Location Name"],
                  ),
                  value: "${data["Location Name"]}",
                )
              );
            }
            return Form(
              key: _formKey,
              child: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                height: 55,
                width: 200,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.black,width: 2)
                ),
                child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
                  child: DropDownField<DropdownMenuItem<String>>(
                    value: value,
                    required: true,
                    items: locationItem,
                    enabled: true,
                    strict: false,
                    itemsVisibleInDropdown: 5,
                    onValueChanged: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        this.value = value!;
                        locationId = value;
                       ** print(value);**
                        print(locationId);
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Is `DropDownField` coming from a package or maybe it is a Widget you created? if it is a package can you share the link of the package you are using? otherwise, can you share the code of your `DropDownField`?

Answer (score 2):

You should use "DropdownButton" or "DropdownButtonFormField" instead of "DropDownField".

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: const Center(
          child: MyStatefulWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  String dropdownValue = 'One';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
      child:DropdownButton<String>(
      value: dropdownValue,
      icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
      elevation: 16,
      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
      underline: Container(
        height: 2,
        color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
      ),
      onChanged: (String? newValue) {
        setState(() {
          dropdownValue = newValue!;
        });
      },
      items: <String>['One', 'Two', 'Free', 'Four']
          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: Text(value),
        );
      }).toList(),
    ),);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is old but probably some newbie like me can get help from this answer.
In my case I declared widget as

```
class CandleStickChartWidget extends StatefulWidget<CandleStikState>
```

instead of

```
class CandleStickChartWidget extends StatefulWidget
```

Correcting to the second line fixed it.